# Giving buttons different names through code and referring to them later on

Tags: vb.net

My code creates a 5x5 grid of buttons. I am wanting to give each of these buttons different names "BtnColour1", "BtnColour2", etc. How do I give them all different names and how do I refer to each button later in the program?

```
Dim bytCounter As Byte
For bytCounter = 1 To 25
        Dim btnColour As New Button
        Me.Controls.Add(btnColour)
        btnColour.Height = 50
        btnColour.Width = 50
        btnColour.Name = "btnColour" & bytCounter
        btnColour.Enabled = False
        btnColour.Left = ((bytCounter - 1) Mod 5) * 51
        btnColour.Top = ((bytCounter - 1) \ 5) * 51
        AddHandler btnColour.Click, AddressOf BtnClick
```

Comment: You are already doing that. To refer to each button in the program, inside the click event,  you can cast the sender to a Button and check its name, like: `If CType(sender, Button).Name = "btnColour1" Then ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refer to the buttons later in the program to change a setting without clicking the button, you can add each button to an array and call each of them with an index number:

```
Dim buttons(24) As Button
```

Then as the buttons are created, you can add each button to the array:

```
Dim bytCounter As Byte
For bytCounter = 1 To 25
        Dim btnColour As New Button
        Me.Controls.Add(btnColour)
        buttons(bytCounter) = btnColour
```

you can then reference each button and their properties using the index number of the button in the array. You may also want to add a specific tag to each button to make each button more unique using:

```
btnColour.Tag = bytCounter
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code (I guess you forgot the ending `Next`) does create 25 Buttons, with names btnColour1... btnColour25.

In the BtnClick event, to get the name of the clicked button, you should write something like:

```
Private Sub BtnClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Dim buttonName as string=CType(sender, Button).Name
  'buttonName now has the clicked button name
End Sub
```

Of course, since you set the `enabled` property to `False`, your button click event will not fire.

Answer (score 1):

In a general sense (and in addition to Spyros' answer, which is a good way to do it in an event handler - the `sender` is always the thing that raised the event), when you give a control a name and add it to a control's `Controls` collection, you can then retrieve it by that name later:

```
'Here you added the button to the form controls:
Me.Controls.Add(btnColour)

'later in the code you can ask for it back by name, for example:
Dim controls = Me.Controls.Find("btnColour1")
```

What you get back is an array of `Control`s. You get an array because Find can search all children (panels inside panels inside groupboxes inside forms etc) and it is thus conceivable that multiple controls in different panels will both have the same name. In your case if you know you only have one control called `"btnColour1"` it's safe to get it by array index:

```
Dim control = controls(0) 'controls variable is from the above Find
```

Lastly, remember that it comes back as a Control, the parent class for all controls. Because you know it's a button, it's safe to cast without check:

```
Dim button = DirectCast(control, Button)
```

Remember that if your property is available on the base Control class you don't even need a cast:

```
'here's a 1 line way to get the text of the button named btnColour1
'Find all controls named btnColour1, take the first, get the text
Dim t = Me.Controls.Find("btnColour1")(0).Text
```